# MapView for IOS7

Tags: xcode

I am new to XCode and trying to use MapView to create an output connection. Every time I try to release the 'line' it just bounces back without making a connection. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have to connect it to an `MKMapView` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check:**

1. The object in the storyboard is actually of MKMapView type
2. The viewcontroller's class is the same as the one you included an IBOutlet for the mapview (check in the identity inspector of the view controller in the storyboard).

(sounds like its issue #2 for you).

Comment: I know this sounds stupid but how do i include a IBOutlet? Thanks again!

Comment: to keep things simple, just add @property IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView in your viewcontroller's .h file, then you will be able to connect the outlet from the view controller to the actual object in the storyboard.